# JDBC BasicDataSource freeze

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

Using `BasicDataSource` to pool jdbc connections. and I am using extensive data reads from a database. I close the connections after I use it

on a windows based netbeans environment record processing happens without a issue . But When I moved it to my production system which uses Linux environment record processing stops after processing like 100 records. Always at the same record. On windows environment this record process without an issue.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: What do you mean with record processing stops? Are there any messages?

Comment: Nope .. just hangs .. feels like memory getting filled

Comment: Change your connection pool size and see if the record changes.